# How to block bluebird promise.map correctly

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise, bluebird

I'm writing a program that performs lots of computationally intensive operations, so I want them to run concurrently, n at a time. I'm trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong with respect to handling my promises. The program doesn't halt at my await and barrels through while still performing some of the computations. I've written this sample program that is basically the same principles:

```js
import * as fs from 'fs';
import * as path from 'path';
import * as bluebird from 'bluebird';

async function main(): Promise<void> {
  const numberOfFiles = 250;
  const Test_Directory = 'testDirectory';
  fs.mkdirSync(Test_Directory);

  const testArray: string[] = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < numberOfFiles; i++) {
    testArray.push(i.toString());
  }

  const result = await bluebird.map(testArray, item => {
    return new Promise( resolve => {
      fs.writeFile(path.join(Test_Directory, `file${item}.txt`), item, () => {});
      console.log(`file${item}.txt`);
      resolve();
    });
  }, {concurrency: 10});
  console.log('done');
 //....
 // do some stuff predicated on the above
```

I expect the await to block my code from continuing until the operations in promise.map have completed. Currently it seems to chug along as soon as the initial 'batch' of concurrent operations runs. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Javascript only has one thread, you can't really do thing simultaniously. You can look into Service-workers for real multi-threading.

Comment: Your promises don't wait for the writeFile to complete `fs.writeFile(path.join(Test_Directory, \`file${item}.txt\`), item, resolve);`